# Transfer SSD from MacBook Pro 2009 to MacBook Pro 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, time-machine, ssd

I'm upgrading from a MacBook Pro  to a 2012 model. I installed a SSD drive on the 2009 unit. A few days ago, I got the black screen of death due to the logic board failing. I back up every 30 days using Time Machine, but was on day 27 or so, which means I need to capture many work days of files; etc.

How do I swap out the 750GB HDD in the 2012 for the SDD in my 2009 with my 2009 not booting up?

Comment: Put the 2009 SSD in an usb enclosure and connect it to the 2012.  Then use the restoration feature in the rescue partition to import the disk to the 2012 drive.  You should after a while have a functional copy.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great website for repair guides called: [iFixit](http://ifixit.com)